# I can't open/ping any antivirus sites

Tags: windows, virus, anti-virus, malware, kaspersky

I have a problem with a virus in windows 7, I don't know what kind of virus is infected my OS, I installed kasersky antivirus, and clear all detected viruses. After that I can't open any antivirus sites, can't ping any antivirus sites.
example:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping kaspersky.com
Pinging kaspersky.com [38.117.98.231] with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 38.117.98.231:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

When I ping to other sites, I get reply normally:
example woth pinging to google.com

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [31.7.160.224] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 31.7.160.224: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 31.7.160.224: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 31.7.160.224: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=61
Reply from 31.7.160.224: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 31.7.160.224:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms
```

I tryed any antispyware/antimalware softwares, but null results.

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: You're saying you tried other antivirus software. Can you please give us a list of them?

Comment: Kaspersky Internet security, SUPERAntiSpyware Free Edition, Malwarebytes, Dr.Web CureIt!

Comment: Someone had a similar issue with McAffee: http://forums.techguy.org/windows-vista/695935-solved-general-failure-message-command.html  -- looks like it could be the antivirus blocking certain things, check the firewall settings.

Comment: Can you ping when every antivirus software is (temporary) disabled?

Comment: Can you ping your own router and 8.8.8.8?

Comment: I have the same problem. I even tried with no Antivirus software installed. when i installed Kaspersky internet security it cant even update because update servers are blocked too. i could update it only using proxy server. when using proxy server the sites are opening too.
and i can ping 8.8.8.8. I have real IP, Don`t have router and i can ping my gateway too.

Comment: I have a normal ping to other sites, to gateway, to dns server, all is good, I can't ping/open only antiviruses sites, I can't update my antivirus database (can't connect to update server)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer found here**: http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-631539-i-can-t-open-antivirus-sites

> The reason is that you may already have an infection which prevents
>   such sites from opening to keep your system infected.
>
> Try this:
>
> - Boot into safe mode (tapping F8 while booting) with networking.
> - Download, install and run Malwarebyte which you can find on this site:
>
> http://en.kioskea.net/telecharger/telecharger-105-malwarebytes-anti-malware
>
> - Ensure you make an update.
> - Please request a FULL system scan, which may take from 20 minutes to
>     hours. Do not interfere no matter how long in takes. The creators of
>     Malwarebyte recommend that while the tool is running that you go do
>     something else, such as watching a rerun of Gone with the Wind or read
>     Tolstoy's War and Peace.
> - If Malwarebyte restarts your system, launch it again to finish the
>     Full scan.
> - When the scan is completed, delete all items found.
> - Once your computer is clean and working normally just to be on the
>     safe side*
>
>   - Turn off system restore and wait 30 seconds,
>   - Turn it back on and create a new restore point.
>
>     *This way it gets rid of anything bad that might have gotten saved in a
>       restore point and you have a clean restore point to use in the near
>       future if needed.
> - Do not turn it off until your computer is clean and
>     working normally because you might need to use it if something goes
>     wrong during the clean-up process.  It is better to go back to an
>     infected restore point if something goes wrong then to not be able to
>     undo changes that were damaging.

Comment: He's definitely infected with something.  He is resolving google.com to 31.7.160.224 which appears to be a server in Armenia.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main reason behind this is that the virus has infected your system to a greater extent. It is happening due to that only and these infected programs does not allow you to register to any antivirus site. The best option to get rid of this is to run your system in safe mode and install an antivirus and then make the updates in the system and delete all the unwanted programs from the system. By doing this, you can protect your system. But the best way is obviously to take the required measures in advance and load your system with good http://www.antivirus4u.co.za/>Antivirus Software.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sysinternals' AutoRuns can help you to find , stop and delete that virus.
It shows ALL processes, services and programs which starts with Windows
(but you can't see all with MSConfig...).
If you know main processes of your Windows, you can find and delete virus easily.
Download it [here](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/Autoruns.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Double check your network settings.

You'll probably find that the DNS server address has been changed to one controlled by the malware writers. They do this so that you can't easily get to the sites you need to clean the infection off your machine.

Go to your ISP's web site and find out what DNS servers (if any) they recommend. Make a note of the IP addresses.

Then open the local area network connection properties dialog, select "Internet Protcol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and then select the "Properties" option.

In the "General" tab of the next dialog there is an option to set the DNS Server. Set this to the IP addresses specified by your ISP or change it to the "Obtain DNS server address automatically option". Click OK, on each dialog to close it.

You should now be able to see all the anti-malware sites.

Do this before and after you've cleaned the system.

You could also try the Google DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why previous answer was deleted. Don't you guys' know how Conficker work?
First try to browse this page first, see if you were infected:
http://www.confickerworkinggroup.org/infection_test/cfeyechart.html

Try use this tool to detect.. the rest you could find on Conficker removal tools:

http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/conficker-removal-tool.aspx